# Error with recursive function in m-file

Tags: matlab

I'm working on chapter 8 of A Course in Mathematical Biology. The textbook uses Maple, but includes this link, [Computer course of Chapter 8 in Matlab](http://www.math.ualberta.ca/~thillen/Matlab_Course.pdf). I'm told to put the following in an m-file:

```
% defining a recursive function in an m-file

function y = plot_traj(a)
RM = inline('a*x.*exp(-x)', 'a', 'x')
% Note that we are using an inline function. Sometimes it’s easier to do this.

% collecting list of x-coordinates
for i = 1:31,
X(i) = i - 1
end

% collecting list of y-coordinates
for i = 1:30,
Y(i+1)=RM(a,iter(i));
iter(i+1) = Y(i+1);
end

y = plot(X, Y, '*');
```

Now, save your m-file (as plot traj.m) and close it. Type the following into the command window:

```
>> plot traj(0.8) 
>> plot traj(1.0) 
>> plot traj(5.0) 
>> plot traj(8.0) 
>> plot traj(13.0) 
>> plot traj(14.5) 
>> plot traj(20.0)
```

However, when I type `plot traj(0.8)` into the command window I get this:

```
>> plot_traj(0.8)
Undefined function or variable "iter".

Error in plot_traj (line 13)
Y(i)=RM(a,iter(i));
```

I don't see anything wrong with line 13, and I've made sure that my code is exactly what is in the chapter. I've been doing fine with the codes up until this point. I'd appreciate it if anyone could provide some assistance. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem at line 13 is that the `iter` local variable array has not been defined.  So on the first iteration, the code tries to access `iter(1)` and fails.  I looked at the link you provided and they missed it too.  Based on previous examples in the Matlab_Course.pdf (and figure 8.6), the `iter` array should be initialized as

```
iter(1) = 1.0;
```

Just add this line prior to the `for` loop and you should be good to continue.  I suspect also that this line should be added too (again based on the document)

```
Y(1)=iter(1);
```

to make sure that both *iter* and *Y* have the same length.

Note that it is a good habit to pre-allocate memory to arrays to avoid the internal resizing of matrices/arrays on each iteration of the loop (which can have a negative impact on performance).  For this loop

```
for i = 1:30,
    Y(i+1)=RM(a,iter(i));
    iter(i+1) = Y(i+1);
end
```

you can observe that `i` iterates over 1 through 30, and we always populate `Y(i+1)` and `iter(i+1)`.  So both `Y` and `iter` are 31x1 vectors.  We can allocate memory to each prior to entering the `for` loop as

```
iter = zeros(31,1);
Y    = zeros(31,1);

iter(1) = 1;
Y(1)    = iter(1);
```

The same should be done for `X` as well.

Comment: Thank you for an excellent answer! I will keep your note in mind.